# Cannot access Node.JS Backend via localhost

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, socket.io

I'm working to setup a Node backend to feed data and communicate with ReactJS for my frontend. Ultimately I am developing new company software to replace our current Transportation System.

I utilize Amazon EC2 Ubuntu 16.04 - for my own reasons for my business - and I simply cannot get my ReactJS frontend with Socket.IO to communicate with my nodeJS backend with Socket.IO on http://localhost:4000/.

This is my App.js in my react frontend

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import logo from './logo.svg';
import ioClient from 'socket.io-client';
import './App.css';

var socket;

class App extends Component {

  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      endpoint: 'http://localhost:4000/'
    };
    socket = ioClient(this.state.endpoint);
  }
```

This is my nodeJS index for the backend

```
const mysql = require('mysql');
const http = require('http');
const express = require('express');
const cors = require('cors');

const app = express();
const server = http.createServer(app);
const io = require('socket.io').listen(server);

//app.use(cors());

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    res.send('Server running on port 4000')
});

const sqlCon = mysql.createConnection({
    host: 'localhost',
    user: 'admin-user',
    password: 'admin-pass',
    database: 'sample'
});

sqlCon.connect( (err) => {
    if (err) throw err;
    console.log('Connected!');
});

io.on('connection', (socket) => {
    console.log('user connected');
});

server.listen(4000, "localhost", () => {
    console.log('Node Server Running on 4000')
});
```

I can get it to communicate via my actual Public IP address, but not via localhost. I really don't want to expose my backend on my public IP address to communicate with it for all users. This has probably been asked before, but I honestly can't find a clear answer for it anywhere and I've been looking for 3 days now. Node has no problem executing, and like I said if I create the socket.io connection from the public IP, I can get it to communicate and as far as I can tell node has no problem running the rest of the script as it connects to mariaDB no problem.

Comment: You've commented out `app.use(cors)` -- the backend domain `localhost:4000` will be different form your react domain `localhost:3000` which will trigger cross-origin blocking

Comment: Even with cors enabled it won't connect to the localhost and I'm currently in development so I have my react frontend port of 3000 reverse proxied in nginx.

Comment: This is the error i keep receiving in my Console on Chrome

`polling-xhr.js:271 GET http://localhost:4000/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=Mv8WHgA net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED`

This is with CORS uncommented

Comment: @elisciandrello did you fix this, if so how?

Comment: @LukePrior super late response, I know. I've actually moved forward to using hooks and axios to retrieve and push data moving forward and that's how I've fixed it, socket.io just became irrelevant at the time because it became too much of a pain.